# Please look at this code and tell which sorting algorithm it is

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I coded it instinctively and i am having difficulty to assume in which sorting algorithm does this fit.

```
int ar[]={8,5,20,-1,50,21};

for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)   
             
        {    for(int j=i+1;j< ar.length;j++)
                {
                   if(ar[i]>ar[j])
                     {  int t=ar[i];
                        ar[i]=ar[j];
                        ar[j]=t;
                
                     }
                }
         }
```

Comment: If I tell you "this is one of insertion sort, selection sort, or bubble sort", can you figure out which one and explain why?

Comment: i know that its not insertion sort definitely. Problem is to place it between selection of bubble sort. The conflict is that here i am not comparing adjacent elements repeatedly so may be its not a bubble sort. Looks like selection but not using minimum index here.

Comment: You're right. It is not insertion sort, and it can't be bubble sort since the swaps are not on adjacent elements. It is selection sort; at every iteration of the outer loop, you select the minimum element of the remainder array, and put it in position i. You're right that other implementations of selection sort usually try to keep track of the index of the minimum element, so as to perform only one swap. This is because we often assume that swaps are relatively slow, so we try to have few of them.

Comment: However, in order to keep track of the index of the minimum, you'll have to manipulate indices. Here you're swapping values in the array. Since your array is an array of integers, and indices are integers too, then swapping values or manipulating indices is not extremely different in terms of speed.

Comment: ok i got it , i am swapping here each time the value is greater, so if i use a minimum index i will have to swap only once each iteration of the outer loop.Thanks.!!!